# how to find array size in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

### How to find array size in AngularJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="namesCtrl">

<p>Looping with objects:</p>
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in names">
    {{ x.name}}
  </li>
</ul>

</div>
```

```
    $scope.names = [
        {name:'Jani'} ,
        {name:'raaj'} 
    ];
});
```

```
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

here i need size of names array

Comment: You mean, like $scope.names.length ?

Comment: You did not specify if you wanted to display the length in the view, or use it in the controller, so, where do you want to use it?

Comment: in view i want to display count

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Just use the `length` property of a `JavaScript` array like so:

```
$scope.names.length
```

Also, I don't see a starting `<script>` tag in your code.

If you want the length inside your view, do it like so:

```
{{ names.length }}
```

Comment: It works but in console also print 'Cannot read property 'length' of undefined'

Answer (score 6):

You can find the number of members in a Javascript array by using its `length` property:

```
var number = $scope.names.length;
```

<sup>Docs - [Array.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length)</sup>